# метод половинного деления. неправильно рассчитывает

Tags: c

пишу на си метод половинного деления.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #define PI 3.14159
    #define E 1e-5
    #define A -5
    #define B 2

    double formula (double b) {
        double function_res = 2*b*b-9; //пока считаю по этой функции и все равно неправильно
//pow(b, 3)* cos(3*PI*b)*exp(b)-pow(b,2)*cos(2*PI*b)*exp(0.5*b)+5;
        return function_res;
    }

    void halfDiv () {
        double* a = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        a[0] = A;
        double* b = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        b[0] = B;
        double* c = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        c[0] = (a[0] + b[0])/2;
        double* distance = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        distance[0] = abs(b[0]-a[0]);
        double* fa = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        fa[0] = formula(a[0]);
        double* fb = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        fb[0] = formula(b[0]);
        double* fc = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        fc[0] = formula(c[0]);
        int i = 0;
        printf("a\t\tb\t\tc\t\t|b-a|\t\tf(a)\t\tf(b)\t\tf(c)\n%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", a[0], b[0], c[0], distance[0], fa[0], fb[0], fc[0]);
        while (abs(distance[i] - E)*1e+5 > 10) {
            i++;
            a = (double*)realloc(a, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            b = (double*)realloc(b, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            c = (double*)realloc(c, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            distance = (double*)realloc(distance, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            fa = (double*)realloc(fa, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            fb = (double*)realloc(fb, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            fc = (double*)realloc(fc, (i +1)*sizeof(double));
            a[i] = (fc[i - 1]<0) ? c[i - 1] : a[i - 1];
            b[i] = (fc[i-1]>0) ? c[i-1] : b[i-1];
            c[i] = (a[i]+b[i])/2;
            distance[i] = abs(b[i]-a[i]);
            fa[i] = formula(a[i]);
            fb[i] = formula(b[i]);
            fc[i] = formula(c[i]);
            printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", a[i], b[i], c[i], distance[i], fa[i], fb[i], fc[i]);
        }
        double x = c[sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0])-1];
        double fx = formula(x);
        printf("\n\nx = %lf\nf(x) = %lf");
        return;
    }



    int main()
    {
        halfDiv();
        return 0;
    }
```

вот код. но почему-то он все считает неправильно. ни функция неправильна, ни даже distance, которую программа рассчитывает вообще непонятно каким боком. все ж вроде в одном типе данных. подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: Методом половинного деления можно решать ряд задач, а задача то какая?

Comment: Как минимум у вас приведен не весь код, оценить сложно.
`ни даже distance` - чему равны A и B мы не знаем

Comment: Зачем вам массив? a и a2 b и b2 ... И ещё одно.... Изюминка метода: **дельта** меньше **епсилон**. это у вас и нарушено. Т.е. `abs(значение_текущее - значение предыдущее) < Epsilon` если у вас 10 - епсилон, то что тогда E ? Грубо говоря `distance[i] - distance[i-1]` должно быть (вместо distance-E), но при начальных условиях может быть загвоздка, поэтому используют do-while цикл, а не while-do.

Comment: Ага, у вас distance это и есть дельта. Ну... тогда выражение `distance[i]=abs(b[i]-a[i]);` мне не нравится. Наберите в гугл метод, полистайте, например вот http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread246601.html хорошая реализация.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: `double halfDiv (double a, double b) {
    double x = (a + b) / 2;
    while (abs(b - a) > 0.00001) {
        if (formula(b)*formula(x)<0) a = x;
        else b = x;
        x = (a + b)/2;
    }
    return x;
}`

вот такая функция. но неправильно считает. почему? может я допустил где-то грубую ошибку?

Comment: у меня похоже с компилятором проблема. счас вставил код в онлайн компилятор. все правильно считает

Comment: Ещe https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317903/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: спасибо за помощь!